# How to focus the <textarea> element that is located in shadowRoot in javascript or jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

DOM structure is shown like this :

[image]

I just wanna give the `focus()` event to this Textarea element, but it does not work.

The code snap that I tried is:

```
var email_text_box_pr = $('kat-textarea');
var email_text_box_sr = email_text_box_pr[0].shadowRoot;
email_text_box = $(email_text_box_sr).find('textarea');
email_text_box.focus();
```

Hope to get any help from anyone as soon as possible.

Regards!

Answer (score 0):

You can do following to give focus attribute to Textarea.

```
<textarea autofocus/>
```

It is simplest way not using JS or JQuery.

Comment: sorry, the site is not my own, and I work in javascript extension. so it is impossible.

Comment: I used it with javascript. And it works

Comment: since the site is not my own, how can I update the HTML content? maybe, do I need to add the "autofocus" attribute to textarea tag? then works?

Comment: Can you share your code? So that I can help you.